# Why aren't the voting buttons disabled on this locked answer?

Tags: bug, locked, locked-answers

So I recently noticed that locked questions lose all the voting buttons on the question and its answers (which definitely makes sense, condidering you can't vote on locked posts).

[Example:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/840973)

http://img.skitch.com/20120313-ffdys83p9spn89dat2jy1skgnn.jpg

I soon realised that this also happens on [locked answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/840973):

http://img.skitch.com/20120313-1gq3fi491fe75pbiaj23is7s8k.jpg

I was totally getting used to this, but then suddenly out of nowhere came [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/273363/93820) on Super User. See that, it's locked, yet the voting things still appear:

http://img.skitch.com/20120313-1hx59uxxibpb7hm9krsqt1wmd.jpg

I tried to find an example of a locked question on SU to see whether it was happening on those as well, but couldn't find any... an `is:locked` search feature perhaps?

But anyway, what's going on here?

---

Edit: turns out you can do `locked:1`

Comment: Locked posts have notices I believe, you could search for `hasnotice:1`.

Comment: @Mat - thanks: [found one](http://superuser.com/q/917/93820) - looks like it's just SU answers then...

Comment: The voting buttons are only supposed to be removed for posts locked as Historical Artifacts - which the SO answer *was* at one point, but is no longer (that's not a lock reason intended for answers). I suspect this is a bug, trying to confirm...

Comment: [By the way...](http://superuser.com/search?q=locked%3A1+answers%3A1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That Super User answer was locked at a time before boilerplate messages saying why it was locked were introduced into the system.

As such, it's not one of the regulars and was just a post that never had its lock updated to one of the three now available (historical baggage; content dispute; offtopic comments) to choose from.

The only lock reason to remove the vote buttons is the "historical wincing archives" option.

The answer was locked because there was a jamboree happening in the comments. Purged and now unlocked to re-enter the exchange with its pants done through the laundry and filling the cup just to the first line because any more and it's just a waste of detergent.

Comment: so unless the lock has been updated to includes one of those messages (i.e. a new lock), it won't lose the arrows?

Comment: Has to be deemed "too important to delete in case of rage abouts" in order for the votes to vamoosh.

Comment: "Locked for hysterical reasons"